# How to restrict other, external user from downloading files from cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am implementing a web application in which I am allowing user's to upload there images and I am going to save those images directly to cloud storage, and I want to allow that specific user only to download or see the image, How can I set such restriction? (oauth protocol is certainly not helpful as it needs google login base authentication)

I want to allow user download image only through my web application, At the moment I am creating signedurl with validity of 10 minutes, but if someone in meantime sees network traffic, and notices the url then other person using that link during those 10 minutes can download the image. So how can I make my system **fullproof**?

Comment: Can't you pass the signed URL over SSL?

Comment: But network administrator or some person who can watch network traffic, will be able to see the url from which I am going to download, and if the person is able to get that url while activation time, person will be able to download the attachment

Comment: How would a network administrator be able to see the URL? URLs are not passed in plain text over SSL connections.

Comment: Ohkey, now I got it, 
So, if I send my request to google server https://storage.googleapis.com/bucketName on this url bu bucketName won't be disclosed to the outside person at all ... Thanks a lot for help... :) ...
This Stack Exchange question help me to understand a bit more
http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34794/if-ssl-encrypts-urls-then-how-are-https-messages-routed
http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work/20847#20847

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ohkey, So moral of the story is, If we send an HTTPS request to the google cloud storage then network administrator or intruders won't be able to see actual full URLs, They only will be able to see the host's IP address on which our request is going to send...

SO if we send our request to https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket/object? then what will actually happen is it will send request to storage.googleapis.com for secure HTTPS connection and once token is generated then it SSL will do its magic and pass remaining URL data to the server, SO, what happens here is, administrator or intruders will know that we are sending request to storage.googleapis.com but won't be able to see our bucketName and other signature stuff

So, our data file stays safe with downloading/uploading over HTTPS connection

This Stack Exchange question help me to understand a bit more https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34794/if-ssl-encrypts-urls-then-how-are-https-messages-routed
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work/20847#20847

Comment: Yes, exactly. Good luck!

Comment: That is correct! However, it's worth noting that URL paths and query params (while hidden over HTTPS) are not a place you want actually sensitive data. They stay in browser history, tend to get logged all over the place on servers, and can be leaked other ways.

Not really an issue in this context, but wanted to mention for anyone stumbling across this question.