# Powerbi report to download file from Google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, google-cloud-storage

I want to use PowerBI dashboard to show a Bigquery table and links with Google storage objects as downloadable files.

The table in BigQuery contains the links of the object stored in Google cloud bucket and can show it as a link in the dashboard. When I click the link it takes me to web browser and using my single signon it is download the file. However, the person who clicks the link should have access to the bucket and all files underneath.

Is there a way to restrict access to Google cloud storage and allow the person to download object from the Powerbi dashboard?

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Naveen Please check the below suggestions and let me know if the below suggestions were helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by generating signed  URLs,Signed URLs can have a time limit associated with them. In your application you would create a signed url for the file and do a HTTP redirect to said file. You can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls)

> A signed URL is a URL that provides limited permission and time to make a request. Signed URLs contain authentication information in their query string, allowing users without credentials to perform specific actions on a resource. When you generate a signed URL, you specify a user or [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts) which must have sufficient permission to make the request that the signed URL will make. After you generate a signed URL, anyone who possesses it can use the signed URL to perform specified actions, such as reading an object, within a specified period of time.The most common uses for signed URLs are uploads and downloads, because in such requests, object data moves between requesters and Cloud Storage.

Comment: Thanks @Sathi Aiswarya. Signed URL's seems the best way to go with. However, I'm  using only BigQuery and looks like we cannot generate singed url using BigQuery UDF's. Is there any other cheaper option to create signed URL's dynamically when we open power BI dashboard?

Comment: can you have a look at the suggestions in this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25927780/18265638)

Comment: Hi @sathi Aiswarya, the post you sent explains security aspects of the signed url's. I'm trying to find how we can generate a signed URL for an object in GCS from BigQuery UDF or power Query.  May be both of these options might not be ideal for my scenario. 
Probably need to run a python script to generate signed URL in cloud run and execute it from power BI when a link is clicked. 
Or I need to re-think of not using power BI and create a web application?

Comment: As generating signed URL from BigQuery UDF or power Query is not possible.You can generate in cloud run but a web application will provide you the flexibility and more control.However, it will depend on your reqiurements and use case.

Comment: @Naveen Have you seen my above comment, please do let me know if the  suggestions were helpful